# Clarification about nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am just starting to learn nodeJS, and also following socket.io basic-chat tutorial.
I have questions, I'm sure they sound ignorant, but I really want to understand them:

1) nodeJS "listens" on `localhost:8080` for example. But let's say I want the socket.io chat to be on a specific page: `localhost/chat.html`, how do I make that chat system to work on `localhost/chat.html`, and not on `localhost:8080`
(so that a user clicks on "chat.html" link and the chat server starts only when in that page)

2) For the chat, I want to allow only users who are registered and logged-in to be able to view that localhost/chat.html page. With PHP I would simply check if a session is set using `isset $_SESSION` and get the id of the user from that session, how can I get the session started by PHP, with the nodeJS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I make that chat system to work on localhost/chat.html, and not on localhost:8080

The default port for HTTP is `80`.  `http://localhost/` implies `http://localhost:80/`.  If you want, you can have Node.js listen on port `80`.

> (so that a user clicks on "chat.html" link and the chat server starts only when in that page)

Well, that part of the question is nonsense.  The server needs to be running so it's available to receive a request when it comes in.

> With PHP I would simply check if a session is set using isset $_SESSION and get the id of the user from that session, how can I get the session started by PHP, with the nodeJS file?

PHP sessions typically work via a cookie.  You can use cookies in your Node.js application as well.  To make this easier on yourself, consider installing Express, and one of the many session data handlers that plug into it as a module.

Comment: Got it, but still something is unclear: now server is listening at localhost:80, alright, but I don't want the chat itself to start only when the user type in the address bar "localhost:80" I want the listener to detect events when a user actually goes to the chat.html link, and not to the address with the port
(Example: My chat file is located at localhost/chat-system/chat.html)

Comment: You're confusing listening (binding to a network address and port) and the HTTP path routing.  They're completely unrelated.  What's hosting your static chat page?

Comment: Definitely, it's just that it's the first time I use nodeJS. The problem is I've never dealt with it. Even the socket.io chat tutorial starts the chat only when you type localhost:8080 at the address bar, what do I need to do to make it work when you type localhost/chat.html instead (assuming that's where the chat file is)? How do you route it in node?

Comment: What does Socket.IO have to do with your static chat page?  I have no idea what your current setup is.  You haven't elaborated on that at all.  I ask again, what is hosting your current page?  You say you've already taken care of the routing and it's at `/chat-system/chat.html`.  So, just change that and make it `/chat.html`?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am following their tutorial at https://socket.io/get-started/chat/  , and that's the setup, they do not explain how to make it work when you directly go to localhost/chat-example/index.html (That's where the chat HTML and CSS are), but instead you have to type localhost:8080 (if I directly type localhost/chat-example/index.html - then events are not being listened to, you can see that nothing happens in the console)

Comment: As I already told you, if you change your server to listen on port `80`, you can use the implicit port `80` in the URL... `http://localhost/`.  As for routing, this tutorial is having you use Express.  The default route is setup with `app.get('/', ...` and it's hardcoded to send `index.html`, which is the file you created.  You can simply change `/` to `/chat.html`, and then I'd rename the file as well.  Better yet, use the Express static middleware.  (Go read the Express documentation for details on how to use that.  https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Will do, thank you for the help! (Didn't realize at first that you meant that when you referred to port 80, btw, only port 80 is implicit? So even if I chat '/' to 'chat.html' I will need to type localhost/chat.html:8080, if I don't change it to 80?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170184/discussion-between-pileup-and-brad).

Comment: @pileup No, that's not at all how that works.  You should do some reading on the parts of a URL and the basics of HTTP before continuing with your application.  If your application is listening on port `80`, and you have a route for `/chat.html`, you can use `http://localhost/chat.html` for your URL.  If you're listening on port `8080`, the URL is `http://localhost:8080/chat.html`.  It's [protocol][host][port][path][querystring].

Comment: My bad about the confusion with the location of the port, clearly I need more research (I'm a beginner as you've guessed), But the more important thing is that, only port 80 allows you to be implicit! So you can't be flexible if you want a "nicer" user experience - if you don't want users to see numbers on the address bar, you have to use port 80? (Or otherwise mess with server config / htaccess files)

Comment: @pileup Yes, you're supposed to use port `80` for HTTP.  It's not as if the browser can read your mind as to what port you want to connect to.  DNS SRV records never really became a thing for HTTP.  Why is this a problem?